# Razer Blade 15 (2019) Fan Control

Tags: kubuntu

Everything seems to be working fine but Im looking for a way to control my fan speeds since razer laptops run hot. Since I cannot use razer synapse nor fan control is there anyway to control the speeds of my fans? I'm currently using the latest release of kubuntu.

Comment: Have a look around in the Bios.  There may be a setting there.  You may be able to control the temperatures there or even just set the fan to run all the time.